# Firebase push notification failed due to 401

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, cordova-plugin-fcm

**Used framework and librarys:**

1. Backend --> spring boot
2. Frontend --> ionic angular
3. Push notification --> Firebase
4. Firebase library --> @awesome-cordova-plugins/firebase-x@6.3.0, cordova-plugin-firebasex@16.0.0

**Error Faced:**

1. Error showing in spring boot (firebase Admin) -->
   com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Unexpected HTTP response with status: 401; body: null
2. Error showing from postman --> InvalidApnsCredential

**Error Explaination:**
Near 30 push notification i was recieved properly, but few hours later the push notification is not working due to above 2 errors and also i was registered p8 file in firebase.

**Working:**
For same project for android platform working fine but ios only facing above mentioned error